# Set iPad launch only in LandscapeRight.

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

This question is not the same from current exist question.

I've set device universal, and only checked landscaperight.

When I launch my app in iPhone, It can work only in landscaperight like expected.

But iPad can rotate, don't know why. Even tried

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method. Hope this can help you out

Open `Info.plish` in your project, find `Supported interface orientations.

[image]

The first one is Supported interface orientations for iPhone, the second one is Supported interface orientations for iPad, you should leave only one row (Landscape) like the picture shows.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I don't why there's two row, but thanks.